# Library common to both Java and Android

Tags: java, android, security, bouncycastle, java-security

I would like to create a security API library common for both java and android development, and would like to confirm that it is possible. I am planning to use BC security provider and would like to know if it would work on both, as I found posts stating Android OS has BC in it.

The main objective here, is having the same library for both desktop application development and Android development. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

> I am planning to use BC security provider and would like to know if it would work on both as I found posts stating Android OS has BC in it.

Correct. Android, at least through Android 4.2, as a cut-down version of the BC library in it.

You could:

- Limit yourself to the portion of `javax.crypto` that the Android SDK supports instead of using BC directly, or
- Use [spongycastle](https://rtyley.github.io/spongycastle/) (a version of BC that is in a different Java package, so it can be used independently of Android's limited BC copy), or
- Use some sort of "plugin" or "driver" approach, where your library delegates the crypto work to something that is platform-specific, so you can use different crypto implementations (e.g., one for Android, one for the JVM)